# Do unintended latches only happen for signals in the process sensitivity list?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I read in one book that an unintended latch requires you to have a process section where there is a signal in the process sensitivity list but don't assign to in every path. But that doesn't make sense to me, because for example you don't assign a value usually to the clock or reset. Also I've read other examples that don't meet this criteria. What is required?

Comment: I think using conditional statements without defining all possible outcomes also produces latches since it has to remember and assume the value with which it entered the section of logic if the conditional statement does not change the value. It might not do that anymore with modern synthesis tools though.

Comment: The signals in the sensitivity list are *inputs* to the process. It is the signals that are assigned to -- the *outputs* -- that need to be assigned in every path in order to avoid creating latches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO.

Latches are generated for the "assigned to" signals. 
You could define these, as Dave Tweed said, as output signals.

Latches appear if you have combinatorial logic where a variable does not get assigned a value in every possible path. 
You find latches by checking every `if, else, case, when` etc. to see if at that point in the code a value has been assigned to every variable.

This is not required for clocked sections. There a variable holds its previous value if no assignment has been made.

Comment: This is going to be slightly confusing for beginners, because a signal that gets assigned in a clocked section, but not in it's asynchronous reset section will also infer a latch. Great answer regardless.

Comment: @DonFusili No, it does not. You just get a register without reset so the start-up state is unknown. I use these a lot in my designs. e.g. register FIFOs where the contents does not need to be cleared. My biggest issue is with a big FPGA vendor who's tool complains about this if you mix signals with and without reset in the same clocked section. (Synopsys has no issue with this.)

Comment: @DonFusili I just tried both ways in Vivado and neither generated a latch.